# Rails migration : Change column type and update existing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rails-migrations

In my Rails project, I have a model object which has an existing column called 'permanent' of type 'Boolean'. I need to change this column to an Integer with possible values of 1, 2, 3. Is there any way for me to update the existing data in the DB (through the rails migration) such that all rows with 'permanent' as false are changed to 1 and all rows with 'permanent' as true are changed to 2.

Comment: Which SQL db you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Postgres. Not sure whether this solution works for other databases.
*people* table used as an example - do not forget to change the table name to your own.

```
  def up
    change_column :people, :permanent, 'integer USING CAST(permanent AS integer)'
    Person.connection.execute("UPDATE people SET permanent = CASE permanent WHEN 0 THEN 1 WHEN 1 THEN 2 END")
  end

  def down
    Person.connection.execute("UPDATE people SET permanent = CASE permanent WHEN 1 THEN 0 WHEN 2 THEN 1 END")
    change_column :people, :permanent, 'boolean USING CAST(permanent AS boolean)'
  end
```

Comment: Above can be done by rake task. It is always better to use SQL queries to do such operations.

Comment: @ray thanks for your advice!
Why is it better to use SQL queries for such operations?

Comment: Actual motive to write migration is to use `ActiveRecord::Migration` methods, here `execute` method will be better one to run SQL to update existing data. Otherwise I could run migration in controller also like `ActiveRecord::Migration.create_table.. if condition`

Comment: Perhaps your answer do not harm and will work properly as if you have provided proper `down` method & handled well. But it do not satisfy coding convention.

Comment: @ray - I updated the solution according to your comments, does it satisfy to coding conventions now?